# CodeIgniter / GroceryCrud : radio button / drop down dependent to unhide hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, dropdown, grocery-crud

before i ask some question i just want to appreciate this is the best CRUD generator for CI/PHP. I'm using this for all of my website.

so my question is, i have some fields in my controller :

```
$crud->display_as('id', 'No')
     ->display_as('name', 'Name')
     ->display_as('address', 'Address')
     ->display_as('phone', 'Phone')
     ->display_as('need_date', 'Need date?')
     ->display_as('date', 'Date');

// this is for radio button
$crud->field_type('need_date','true_false');
```

1. If the active radio button clicked will show the 'date' field
2. if I clicked the inactive button it will hide again the 'date' field

I appreciate all the help that comes, Thank you very much

i already add this line to the view page:

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('field-needdate-yes').checked) {
        document.getElementById('field-date').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else document.getElementById('field-date').style.display = 'block';
}
```

but m problem is that i need to add the ***yesnoCheck*** function to the onClick radio button, but how can i do that?

Comment: Hi, please remember that this isn't a code-writing service. If you genuinely don't know where to start, please edit the question to identify what documentation/articles you have read so far, and why they didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: thanks @MandyShaw , i already edit y question to new question. i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

in the end of controller try to  echo this script or load it as a view,

```
echo '<script>

document.ready(function(){

$(".field-needdate-yes:unchecked").each(function(){
document.getElementById('field-date').style.display = 'none';
});

});

</script>';
```

Comment: change document.ready( ...   to $(document).ready(...